# Why does this method for computing a SHA-256 hash always return a string of 44 characters?

Tags: c#, cryptography

First off, please ignore that there is no salt. I removed the salt in order to simplify things as much as possible.

The following always outputs a 44 character string:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string blah = ComputeHash("PasswordLongBlah646468468Robble");
            Console.WriteLine(blah.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(blah);
        }

        private static string ComputeHash(string input)
        {
            Byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

            Byte[] hashedBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Output of this application:

> 44
>   K5NtMqCN7IuYjzccr1bAdajtfiyKD2xL15Eyg5oFCOc=

If I am not mistaken, the output should be:

> 64
>   2b936d32a08dec8b988f371caf56c075a8ed7e2c8a0f6c4b979132839a0508e7

What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See where it says `Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes)`? It's not giving you a hexadecimal string (4 bits per character) - it's in base 64 (6 bits per character).

Comment: Thanks. Changed to `BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", String.Empty);` and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting it to a Base64 string...

You might want to use this instead:

```
 // Cut bad code
```

Edit: which once again is a poor man's implementation of the BitConverter.ToString() posted above. Why is the internet filled with reimplementations of existing framework functionality when searching for common functionality like "string to hex"? ;-(

Comment: Why is it so hard to discover .NET functionality? Microsoft online documentation of .NET is often quite poor, consisting mainly of cut&paste general information and without much insight into the the classes at all.